# Please explain return with "+1:" in it

Tags: python, string, return, slice, one-liner

Here is the code. 2 functions.

```
def get_domains(self): #returns test@test.com, test2@test.com etc in json. 
    if self.domain_names == None:
        r = requests.get(GET_DOMAINS_URL)
        if r.status_code != 200:
            raise ValueError("Can't get domains")
        self.domain_names = [item["name"] for item in r.json()]
    return self.domain_names

def is_valid_email(self, email):
    return email[email.find("@")+1:] in self.get_domains()
```

So what does part "+1:" in function is_valid_email ? How it works?

Comment: It's the index of the character after the `@` in the email. So it's the start of the domain name.

Comment: So if `email` is `foo@gmail.com`, the slice extracts `gmail.com`

Comment: `find` returns the index of the `@`. If you just did `email[email.find("@"):]`, the slice would include the "@". So, "@example.com". By adding 1, you get the domain name after the @, "example.com".

Comment: This code is also bugged, since str.find returns -1 if the substring is not found, and then adding 1 just slices from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a string slicing:

```
email[email.find("@")+1:]
```

It means - take all the characters from `email` string from the first index after the `@` char till the end of string.

Or in simple words - extract the domain from an email address :)